# Getting error with rsync and scp

Tags: ssh, networking, rsync, scp

My issue is an odd one. I am logged into my University's server with my host name and all that good stuff. I am able to copy files from my local computer into my school's account. My issue, is the other way around. I am unable to transfer files from the school's server onto my local computer. I am fairly certain I have the syntax correct:

`rsync -v username@hostname:~/hw0/hello.cpp .`

the issue is, is that it copies it the home directory in my schools computer. Anyone know how to fix this?

Or even worse, if I use:

`rsync -v username@hostname:~/hw0/hello.cpp /Users/anthony`

I get the error message:

`rsync: change_dir#3 "Users" failed: No such file or directory(2)`

`rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(694) [Receiver=3.1.1]`

So overall, I am pretty sure the issue is, is that the command on my school's server is trying to send it within the server, i.e. NOT to my local computer.

Comment: Are you running those rsync commands on the server or on your Mac?  The way they're written, they should be run on the Mac.

Comment: Yes my local computer is a mac, and the server is using Fedora, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: that's not what i asked.    the exact computer you run them on (the mac, or the remote server via ssh) is extremely significant.  it doesn't matter whether one is a mac or fedora or whatever.  what matters is whether the command is run on the remote computer or the local computer.

Comment: Oh sorry! Yes, I am running those commands off of a mac.

Comment: running them on the mac?  or on the remote computer via ssh?

Comment: if you are running them on the remote computer, you are telling it to connect to itself via ssh and copy the file.  If you run it on the mac, you are telling the mac to connect to the remote computer and copy the file.  see the difference?

Comment: Ok sorry for the confusion, but now I understand what you are telling me. So I ran those commands while I was logged into my school's account; that means that I am telling the remote computer to connect to itself and copy the file. So what exactly is the correct syntax? The code I am using is what I found in my Unix book; it looks like the code is incorrect?

Comment: Unless you are able to ssh back to your Mac from the Uni computer (which might be difficult if you are behind a NAT gateway), just run those rsync commands on the Mac itself.  otherwise you'd run them like `rsync files anthony@mac-host-or-ip:/Users/anthony/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running these `rsync` commands on the remote computer, you are telling it to connect to itself via ssh and copy the file.

If you run them on the Mac, you are telling the mac to connect to the remote computer and copy the file to itself.  I presume this is what you want to do.

There are two basic solutions to this:

1. just run the commands on the Mac itself.  The way they are written, they will just work properly in that context.
2. If you are able to ssh back to your Mac from the Uni computer, you can rewrite the commands so that it is copying local files (local to the remote computer, that is) to the Mac.  From the remote computer's perspective, your Mac is a remote computer.  For example:

   `rsync ~/hw0/hello.cpp anthony@mac-host-or-ip:/Users/anthony/`

Note that if your Mac is behind a firewall or NAT gateway or similar, it may be difficult to connect back to your Mac...but solving that is an entirely different problem needing a question of its own.

Comment: Are you serious! -.- Your first solution worked perfectly! I was issuing the command on the schools computer, that was the first mistake. I was under the impression that I had to be logged into the school's computer for this to work! The book and other sources should of made it clear how the environment where this command is used will affect the results. Thanks so much! I appreciate it!